# php sort the files listing

Tags: php, html

Hi i have php which shows me all files in dir and make them href. in the output i have list of files like kpi_03.03.2015.html, kpi_02.03.2015.html etc.
I need to sort the output by date for example.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
     if ($handle = opendir('/opt/nagios/share/kpi_backup')) {
       while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
          {
              if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
              {
                    $thelist .= '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
              }
           }
      closedir($handle);
      }
echo "list of files:<br><br>";
echo $thelist;
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried lot of variants like:

```
sort($thelist);

for ($i=0; $i <= 4; $i++) 
    echo $thelist[$i]."<br \>";
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: Please add your current output and your expected one

Comment: load the file list to an array and use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array. You can use the sorted array in your loop.

Comment: @Rizier123 kpi_03.03.2015.html, kpi_02.03.2015.html,  kpi_01.03.2015.html etc i need  kpi_01.03.2015.html, kpi_02.03.2015.html, kpi_03.03.2015.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
//Read the file list to array
$thelist = array_diff(scandir('/opt/nagios/share/kpi_backup'), array('..', '.'));

//use usort to sort
usort(
    $thelist,
    function ($a, $b) {
        list($d,$m,$y) = sscanf($a, 'kpi_%d.%d.%d');
        $da = sprintf("%d%02d%02d",$y,$m,$d);
        list($d,$m,$y) = sscanf($b, 'kpi_%d.%d.%d');
        $db = sprintf("%d%02d%02d",$y,$m,$d);
        return $da>$db;
    }
);

$print_list='';
foreach($thelist as $file){
    $print_list .= "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a>";
}
echo $print_list;
```

you can filter the array before sorting. like the following

```
$thelist=array_filter(
    $thelist,
    function($k){
        return !substr_compare($k,'.html',-5);
    }
);
```

Note:[substr_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php) is case sensitive by default

Comment: thanks a lot , can u help once more. I need to output only *.html files

Comment: updated my answer. it shows how to filter the files.

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of base filenames in an array and sort that

```
usort(
    $thelist
    function ($a, $b) {
        $list($d, $m, $y) = explode('.', trim(sscanf($a, 'kpi_[^h]'), '.'));
        $dateA = $y . $m . $d;
        $list($d, $m, $y) = explode('.', trim(sscanf($b, 'kpi_[^h]'), '.'));
        $dateB = $y . $m . $d;
        return $dateA > $dateB;
    }
);
```

then loop the array and display